# append pngdata to file rather than overwrite

Tags: ios, swift

i want data to append to file rather than overwrite in ios while saving file.

How can I do that?

```
 let url = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(photo)")
            print(url)
              try! img!.pngData()?.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
```

Comment: If you "append" two pgndata into one, I'm not sure it will be valid afterward...

Comment: Appending PNG data to the end of a file is quite unusual, and before we tell you how to do that it's worth asking: what are you trying to accomplish? Why do you wan to _append_ PNG data to a file?